# Increase body speed with applyLinearImpulse box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, physics

Im trying to make body move with increaseing speed. At first its starts to accelerate but it reaches a constant speed shortly after. How do I make it keep accelearte?

My code looks like this:

```
 world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
        body.applyLinearImpulse(400f, 0, pos.x, pos.y, true);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
        body.applyLinearImpulse(-400f, 0, pos.x, pos.y, true);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
        body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 400f, pos.x, pos.y, true);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
        body.applyLinearImpulse(0, -400f, pos.x, pos.y, true);
```

Comment: What is the size of your world ? The default Box2D setting is 1 px = 1 m. That means if you want to run your game on a 720 p screen (for example) your world will be 1280 meters by 720 meters, and a small objet of 100 px x 100 px will have a size of 100 m x 100 m, which is huge. Box2D is only good at dealing with "realistic" sizes and speeds. That means using huge size and speed will results in bad simulations and/or limitations as you can observe.

Comment: The solution for that is simple : create a view port with small size, so every objet will be smalls, and box2d won't have problem.
If it is your problem, look at [my answer on this message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29070355/4293811)

Comment: So ? Any update on this problem ? Did you try my solution or Springbua's solution ? Did that work ? If no, what do you observe ?

Comment: I solved it by scaling down the screen to 100f, just like you said the ball was huge in box2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a `Body` accelerate over time, usualy `applyForce` is used, `applyLinearImpulse` is used for immediate speed changes instead.
Remeber, that you have to call `applyForce`, as long as you want to accellerate, while an impulse is usually only applied once.
Think about a starting car: The rotation of the wheels, combined with the friction adds a force to the whole car, accelerating it.
If the car then has got some speed and hits a box, an impulse is applied to the box once, increasing it's speed almost immediately.
So you could try to change the `applyLinearImpulse` call to `applyForce` and make sure it get's called every `update` cycle, as long as you press the given key.

I suggest you to read the [`Box2D` tutorials on iforce2d.net](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/)