# My box2d body drops way too slow

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I tried almost everything but nothing works.
If you run it you will see a square falling down very slow.
I'm a beginner so explain it not too complicated.
Any questions about this code dylan.missu@gmail.com
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(100,100);
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 2;
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
}
private void line(float X, float Y, float w, float h) 
{
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type=BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(X,Y);
    PolygonShape polygonShape=new PolygonShape();
    polygonShape.setAsBox(w,h);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape=polygonShape;
    fixtureDef.restitution=0.4f;
    fixtureDef.friction=0.5f;
    Body theFloor=world.createBody(bodyDef);
    theFloor.createFixture(fixtureDef);
}
private void wall(float A)
{
    // is there a better way of doing this?
    line(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-A,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-A,0);
    line(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-A,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-A);
    line(0,-Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2+A,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-A,0);
    line(-Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2+A,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-A);
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    world.step(1 / 5f, 6, 2);

    OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    processAccelerometer();
    wall(1);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    world.dispose();
    debugRenderer.dispose();
}

private void processAccelerometer() {

    float y = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
    float x = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();

    if (prevAccelX != x || prevAccelY != y) {

        world.setGravity(new Vector2(y, -x));

        prevAccelX = x;
        prevAccelY = y;
    }
}
@Override
public void hide()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void resize(int p1, int p2)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void resume()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void pause()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void render()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Box2D you have to take into account that 1 pixel = 1 meter. So, basically, everything you simulate in Box2D will be HUGE by default. And Box2D simulations are not accurate for huge distances, huge masses, huge speeds...

So all you have to do is convert your viewport with a conversion factor, so you'll just look at small entities, that will be easier to simulate.

For example, let's say you want 100 pixel = 1 meter, you'll put that code when you create your game screen :

```
WORLD_TO_BOX = 1/100f;  
BOX_TO_WORLD = 1/WORLD_TO_BOX;

//Creation of the camera with your factor 100
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * WORLD_TO_BOX;  
camera.viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * WORLD_TO_BOX;  
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0f);  
camera.update();
```

Then, you'll create your boxes in term of `camera.viewportWidth` and `camera.viewportHeight`, instead of `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`

I your case you'll have :

```
PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(camera.viewportHeight/6,camera.viewportHeight/6);
```

You can see in my code, there is also a `BOX_TO_WORLD` conversion factor. It will be used when you want to render graphics over your box2D bodies.
For that, look at the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044249/rendering-box2d-in-libgdx/29070355#29070355).

Comment: I don't really get it, can you implement it in my code and show it to me